# Expo & SpringBoot Multipart Upload Problem

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, upload, expo, multipart

I have been trying for hours now, to upload a file and a JSON using multipart file upload. I use Expo React Native as the client and SpringBoot as the server.

I already tried many different versions. After reading into this a lot, this is how it should work:

**In my Expo app I have this:**

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append(
    'document',
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(json)], {
    type: 'application/json'
}));
formData.append('file', {
    uri: url,
    type: data.type,
    name
});

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', API_URL);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwt);
xhr.onload = () => {
    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    console.log(response);
    // ... do something with the successful response
};
xhr.onerror = e => {
    console.log(e, 'upload failed');
};
xhr.ontimeout = e => {
    console.log(e, 'upload timeout');
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

**In my SpringBoot Backend I have this:**

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/api/upload")
public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadDocument(
    @RequestPart("document") DocumentDTO document,
    @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    // ... my business logic
}
```

Now without the **document** it would work, but as soon as I add the **document** I get this error:
`o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Bad Request: Required request part 'document' is not present`

As a workaround I will upload files as base64 encoded strings for now ... But I really don't understand why this doesn't work, because it should.

Similar issue I think:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30623

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: new Blob??? why? you already added type: 'application/json' so why you convert it to blob? don't get it and what type of document is converted to JSON?

Comment: Did you try setting `multipart/form-data` header on your xhr request?

Answer (score 0):

Try your backend with this approach.  (May try removing Blob in FE, just leave it as
json string)
Create a class to wrap both document and file.

```
@Data
public class FormDataModel {

  private MultipartFile file;

  private DocumentDTO document;

  public void setDocument(String document) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // this requires try-catch block in fact
    this.document = mapper.readValue(document, DocumentDTO.class);
  }
}
```

Use @ModelAttribute at Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/upload", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<Void> uploadDocument(@ModelAttribute FormDataModel wrapper) {
    // ... my business logic
}
```